# Nesting quotes: a message tag inside a javascript fragment inside of an actionsubmit tag

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a submit button where I want a confirmation pop-up, doing this works fine:

```
<g:actionSubmit value="Delete" 
action="deleteTpsReport" 
onclick="return confirm('ohnoes!');"
```

But when I want to move the confirmation text into the messages.properties file I try:

```
<g:actionSubmit value="Delete" 
action="deleteTpsReport" 
onclick="return confirm('<g:message code="tps.delete.confirmation"/>');"
```

which doesn't work, the `');"` gets displayed on the page and the javascript is totally ignored.

Is there a way to nest these tags so that I can use `message` in the event handler of the `actionSubmit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<g:actionSubmit value="Delete" 
action="deleteTpsReport" 
onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'tps.delete.confirmation')}');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try escaping the inner double quotes with the HTML entity equivalent, or with the HTML entity for single quotes:

```
onclick="return confirm('<g:message code=&quot;tps.delete.confirmation&quot;/>');"
```

or

```
onclick="return confirm('<g:message code=&#039;tps.delete.confirmation&#039;/>');"
```